# Obtaining name of a method parameter from the corresponding argument in a method invocation in Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I was wondering if there was some existing logic to obtain the name (or any other relevant information) about the definition of a parameter in its containing  method/constructor signature by looking at an invocation of that particular method/constructor. Basically, I just want to be able to get a default name for a variable that will be passed as an argument to the invocation. So, if a method if defined as such:

```
public void Foo(object firstParam, object secondParam, object thirdParam)
```

I would want to be able to say that the second argument of the following invocation

```
object bar = null;
this.Foo(null, bar, null)
```

is expected to have the name "secondParam". Basically, I just want to relate an argument to the original parameter whose "spot" it occupies in the invocation.

I am asking if any util methods that I am not aware of already exist within Roslyn, as there are some more complex scenarios to handle, such as named or optionnal arguments. The solution I've come up with in the meantime should covers some cases, but probably not all (especially params, which should require some more specialized logic to handle). Here's what I have so far:

```
    private IEnumerable<IdentifierNameSyntax> GetParameterNamesFromArgumentList(ArgumentListSyntax argumentList, SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        var arguments = argumentList.Arguments;
        var parameters = argumentList.Parent.GetSymbolOrDeclaredAs<IMethodSymbol>(context)?.Parameters;

        if (parameters != null)
        {
            var index = 0;
            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            {
                var argument = index < arguments.Count ? arguments[index] : null;

                if (argument != null && argument.NameColon == null)
                {
                    yield return SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName(parameter.Name);
                }
                else if (argument != null)
                {
                    yield return argument.NameColon.Name;
                }

                index++;
            }
        }
    }
```

I could be using `DeclaringSyntaxReferences`on the method symbol, but I think that just having the names from the `IParameterSymbol` suited my needs well enough. Again, if this kind of logic is already implemented anywhere else, I'd rather use it. If not, well, feel free to tell me what you think of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly I don't think there is a good public way to do this.  See Roslyn's internal [`DetermineParameter`](http://source.roslyn.io/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces/R/af94352fb5da7056.html) helper for something that might help.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. It seems very similar the the approach I took, but at least this confirms that this I was on the right path. Oh, the pain of finding all those incredibly useful methods in classes with that treacherous "internal" in front of their name in the reference source...

Comment: Yep. One thing I'd like to get fixed in reference source is substring searching so that at least searching for `Parameter` would have included that method.