# Finding declaration of a variable passed as parameter in Roslyn C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, roslyn, analyzer

## **Introduction**

I am creating an analyzer using Roslyn as part of a project, and am wondering if it is possible to find out how a variable that is passed as an argument in a function call is defined/assigned.

*For example I have the following code:*

```
string url = Request.QueryString["url"];
Response.Redirect(url);
```

## **How I thought I should go about it**

I have code that finds LocalDeclarationStatement's and evaluates the variables initializer to see if it contains "Request.QueryString"; thereby verifying that the variable url is assigned by user input. It then traverses through each InvocationExpressionSyntax looking for Response.Redirect containing the IdentifierName "url" in the ArgumentList. If user submitted url is contained in a Response.Redirect invocation, the analyzer should create the rule.

```
foreach (VariableDeclaratorSyntax dec in varDec)
{
   if (dec.Initializer != null)
   {
      if (dec.Initializer.ToString().Contains("Request.QueryString"))
      {
           foreach (InvocationExpressionSyntax invocation in invocExpression)
           {
             if (invocation.Expression.ToString().Contains("Response.Redirect") && invocation.ArgumentList.Arguments.ToString().Contains(dec.Identifier.ToString()))
              {
                 context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, invocation.ArgumentList.GetLocation()));
              }
           }
       }
  }
```

I quickly realized this was not the correct way to solve my problem because if I were to have code such as:

```
string url = "Not user input";
Response.Redirect(url);
url = Request.QueryString["url"];
Response.Redirect(url);
```

Then not only would my analyzer flag the intended invocation (the last one) of Response.Redirect, but also the first one that does not actually contain a variable defined/assigned by user input.

## **My Goal**

What I would like to do is look for invocation's of Response.Redirect(url), and analyze the argument 'url' to determine whether or not it was defined/assigned by user input. As of now, I can't think of any way to, in a sense, go backwards from having a variable to finding the definition or assignment of it. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242345/obtaining-name-of-a-method-parameter-from-the-corresponding-argument-in-a-method) stackoverflow question pertaining to finding information about parameters but they just wanted to retrieve the name.

If anyone has any insight on whether or not this is possible to do in Roslyn and could point in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.
Thanks!

Comment: You need the semantic model and DataFlow.

Comment: You could use `SymbolFinder.FindAllReferences` to find all the references to your `url` symbol and see if any of these references is enclosed by a call to `Response.Redirect`. Likewise you could use `ISymbol.GetDeclaringSyntaxReferences` to get the declaration and see if it is declared with `Request.QueryString`. The SymbolFinder, however, is not available in an analyzer though you could mimic it by traversing all identifier nodes from the root of a given tree and comparing them all. Seems all a bit convoluted though.

Comment: @Jeroen I tried implementing ISymbol.GetDeclaringSyntaxReferences and it seems to only get declarations. In the event that the variable url gets assigned a new value, is it possible to get the SimpleAssignmentExpressionSyntax from that as well?

Comment: No, that's why you would use `FindAllReferences`. Or, as @SLaks said, you could dataflow analysis if it's all contained in a single method.

Comment: We've got a similar thing where we wanted to flag all SimpleMemberAccessExpressions for parameters of public methods that don't have a (PostSharp) NotNull attribute.  I would start with all member accesses in a method and walk up the tree looking for the assignments then through all member access to response.redirect that have any of those assigned to vars as the parameter